# Split list of Strings and extrat elements to a new List

Tags: list, haskell, split, average

I have a list of Strings like `["1,2,3", "4,5,6", "7,8,9"]` and I'm trying to split the Strings in `[["1","2","3"], ["4","5","6"], ["7","8","9"]]` and then i'm trying to from a new list where a only have like all the second elements (from example) from the lists in a new list like `[2,5,8]`, and then calculate the average of this elements.

My last attempt was this:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List

removeComa :: [String] -> [String]
removeComa [] = []
removeComa (x:xs) = splitOn "," x : removeComa xs --ERROR HERE

contentsFromCol :: [String] -> Int -> [Int]
contentsFromCol [] _ = []
contentsFromCol (x:xs) c = read x !! c ++ contentsFromCol xs c

average' :: [String] -> Int -> IO()
average' content col = do
    let contents = removeComa content
    let contents' = contentsFromCol contents col
    realToFrac (sum contents') / genericLength contents'
```

but I keep getting `Variable not in scope: splitOn :: [Char] -> String -> String` and i don't understand why?

Comment: You need to install the `split` package, and import it from `Data.List.Split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I keep getting Variable not in scope: `splitOn :: [Char] -> String -> String` and i don't understand why?

Because there is no `splitOn` function in the `Prelude`, in fact there is not a `splitOn` in the `base` package.

You need to install the `split` package, for example with `cabal install split`, or by adding `split` to the dependencies of the stack project, and then import it from `Data.List.Split`:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split(splitOn)

removeComa :: [String] -> [[String]]
removeComa = map (splitOn ",")
```

This will also return a list of list of strings, so `[[String]]`. In your `contentsFromCol`, you should use `!! c` on the row, not on the result of `read x`:

```
contentsFromCol :: [[String]] -> Int -> [Int]
contentsFromCol [] _ = []
contentsFromCol (x:xs) c = read (x !! c) : contentsFromCol xs c
```

Your `average'` function however does not make much sense: `realToFrac … …` has not as type `IO ()`, so that will raise an error as well.

You can implement this with:

```
average' :: Fractional a => [String] -> Int -> a
average' content col = fromIntegral (sum contents') / genericLength contents'
    where contents' = contentsFromCol (removeComa content) col
```

Comment: can i use strSplitAll instead of splitOn and avoid the install or the extra import?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @oneuser: I don't find where `strSplitAll` is defined, exactly where should that be located. You can however implement a `splitOn` here for a comma by constructing such function yourself with a combination of `span` and recursion.